# Needs & past tense

Tags: american-english

I've heard a Canadian friend of mine say, "He needs hit" rather than "he needs to be hit". Is this an Americanism/Canadianism or is it just a quirk of my friend's idiolect? I think I've heard similar things said by other North Americans, so I'm pretty sure that it's current colloquially, but I can't be sure.

Comment: I usually associate that with the Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania dialect.

Comment: See ["Needs washed"](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/needs-washed) at the Yale Grammatical Diversity Project.